# How to validate Identityserver4 token validation in webapi?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3, webapi

Have you tried to ID4 connect with web api (.net framework 4.6) I follow below the tutorial but APIResource with secret key is not working. it also not giving any error if I give wrong API resource name and secret.

https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/

**Source code**

```
var IDSBearerOption = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
Authority = "https://localhost:5000",
ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local,
RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" },
PreserveAccessToken = true,
RoleClaimType = "role",
ValidAudiences = new[] { "TestAPI1" } ,
ClientId = "TestAPI1", //api resource name
ClientSecret = "secret1" //api resource secret

};

app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(IDSBearerOption);
```

Is it possible to validate the token in webapi .net framework4.6?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to share cookies and set your bearer token auth options inside OWIN in startup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            CookieName = "MySharedCookieName"
            
        });

app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            
            Authority = authorityUrl,
            RequiredScopes = new[] {"MyAPIName"},
            ClientId = "MyAPIName",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
            NameClaimType = "name", 
            RoleClaimType = "role",
            SigningCertificate = x509Cert

        });
```

Just make sure your cookie names match in IDS4 and all other apps